# Evaluating $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin{mt}\sin{nt}}{a+b\cos{nt}}dt$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, trigonometric-integrals

How can the following integral be evaluated?

> $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin{mt}\sin{nt}}{a+b\cos{nt}}dt$$
>
> for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have tried some substitutions and developing that $\sin{mt}$ into a combination of powers of $\sin{t}$, but with no success.

**Edit:** We can assume $a>0$, $b<0$, $|a|>|b|$, $n>1$, $m>>1$

Any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin{mt}\sin{nt}}{a+b\cos{nt}}dt$$

By enforcing the substitution $t\mapsto-t$,
$$I=\int^0_{-\pi} \frac{\sin{mt}\sin{nt}}{a+b\cos{nt}}dt$$

Then, we can see
$$2I=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \frac{\sin{mt}\sin{nt}}{a+b\cos{nt}}dt$$

Let $z=e^{it}$, the integral equals
$$-\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{(z^m-z^{-m})(z^n-z^{-n})}{2a+b(z^n+z^{-n})}\frac{dz}{iz}$$
$$=i\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{(z^{2m}-1)(z^{2n}-1)}{(z^{m+1})(2az^n+bz^{2n}+b)}dz$$

The poles are:

1. $z=0$, of order $m+1$, or, of order $m+n+1$ if $b=0$.
2. For $b\ne0$, $z^n=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$, which gives $2n$ roots.

I cannot further generalize it. Indeed, calculation of residue at each pole is tedious as well. Moreover, you need to do some work to determine if the pole lies inside the unit circle.

I am searching for some better solutions...

**EDIT:**

For simplicity, assume $n>1$.

Then, between $0$ and $\pi$, $\cos(nt)$ attained all possible values at least once.

Thus, if $\frac{\cos^{-1}(-a/b)}n$ is real, your integrand must have a singularity within the integration interval. Thus, your integral becomes improper, which I would not want to deal with at the moment.

Therefore, I assume $\vert\frac{a}{b}\vert>1$.

According to my analysis, for $\frac{a}{b}>0$, only the positive roots will lie within the unit circle(i.e. only consider $+$ in $\pm$). for $\frac{a}{b}<0$, only the negative roots will lie within the unit circle(i.e. only consider $-$ in $\pm$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not understand your edit. We can assume $a>0$. If $a$ is sufficiently large wrt $b$, the denominator will never be zero

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add that information in my question. My fault

Comment: @user3141592 Well, my edit simply implies half of the 2n poles will lie inside the unit circle, which make the problem a little easier.

Comment: Well, it is possible to use the formula for a residue of order $n$ for the pole at $z_0=0$. And we may express the other polynomial as $\prod_k |z| e^{i\frac{ak}{2\pi}}$ for suitable $a$ in terms of $n$

Comment: Well, computing these residues for some arbitrary constants seem to be huge compared to the global result of the integral

Comment: @user3141592 So do you know the global result?

Comment: No, I just computed the original integral using NIntegrate in Mathematica for some arbitrary $a, b, n, m$ and compare the result with the sum of the residues

Comment: @user3141592 If $m$ is a multiple of $n$, things get easier.